# Why onchange event not working for elementor?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, elementor

I am developing a WP Elementor widget. I want to get a value (`onChange` event) from Select dropdown but it's not working `onChange` event. The code below is from elementor dropdown:

```html
<select id="elementor-control-default-c776" data-setting="lead_contact">
  <option value="Contacts">contact</option>
  <option value="Leads">Lead</option>
</select>
```